# Помогите создать сервис, который будет уведомлять о наступающем событии из SQLite

Tags: android

Как заставить сервис выполнять один и тот же код в определенное время, например каждый день в 9 утра.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_white_48dp)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_add_white_48dp))
                .setTicker("Check your movies")
                .setWhen(calendar.getTimeInMillis())
                .setContentTitle("Time for watching!")
                .setContentText("qq")
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        notif = builder.build();
        nm.notify(1,notif);
```

В чем ошибка? уведомление всплывает сразу, а не по моему расписанию.

Comment: Вам нужен AlarmManager - он позволит выполнять отложенную задачу в чётко заданное системное время. В т.ч. с любым интервалом - например раз в день

Comment: Я правильно понял, что на самом деле вам надо узнать, как выполнить код по расписанию?

Comment: @metalurgus, да, вопрос про расписание

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте его, чтобы он не содержал ничего лишнего, и отражал действитеольно то, что вы хотите узнать.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20alarmmanager%20example

Comment: @batman, посмотрите ответ в дублирующем вопрос - так весь нужный код, который вы можете адаптировать под ваши нужды, установив начальное время запуска и изменив период между повторными вызовами